# Unknown error in paypal integration

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to integrate **Paypal** to my website but its been a lot of chaos.

The documentation doesn't seem to match with the **`PHP SDK`** of theirs and hence its been a trouble please suggest appropriate integration method.

The code I have tried out is as follows :

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    require __DIR__  . '/bootstrap.php';
    // 3. Lets try to save a credit card to Vault using Vault API mentioned here
    // https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#store-a-credit-card
    $apiContext->setConfig(
    array(
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => 'PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG'
      )
    );
    $creditCard = new \PayPal\Api\CreditCard();
    $creditCard->setType("visa")
        ->setNumber("403*************")
        ->setExpireMonth("09")
        ->setExpireYear("2020")
        ->setCvv2("123")
        ->setFirstName("J***")
        ->setLastName("M*****");
    $fi = new \PayPal\Api\FundingInstrument();
    $fi->setCreditcard($creditCard);
    $payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentmethod('credit_card');
    $payer->setFundinginstruments(array($fi));
    $amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('USD');
    $amount->setTotal('7.47');
    $transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);
    $transaction->setDescription('This is the payment transaction  description.');
    $payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('sale');
    $payment->setPayer($payer);
    $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));
    // 4. Make a Create Call and Print the Card
    try {
        //$creditCard->create($apiContext);   
        //$creditCard->create($apiContext);       
        $payment->create($apiContext);
        echo $payment;
    }catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
         // This will print the detailed information on the exception. 
        //REALLY HELPFUL FOR DEBUGGING
        echo $ex->getData();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: "Trying... integrate Paypal... lot of chaos... add credit card...." - Please don't use Paypal. Payment stuff isn't for beginners. Not to be offensive, but to safe customers some trouble.

Comment: Would have been a great help if i get an answer

Comment: You didnt even show what error you get, how do you expect an answer?

Comment: Error that is displayed is UNKNOWN ERROR - "An unknown error occurred"

Comment: How is it reproducable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Vault you need to have been approved to accept direct credit cards. You will need to make certain that the application that you have submitted for Rest API and Vault has been fully approved for direct credit cards. 
From the PayPal Developer Site:

> **Store and use a customer credit card**
>     Direct credit card payment and related features are restricted in some  countries.

[Vault Information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/)

Here is additional information on Going Live with your Application: 
[Apps 101](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/)

Here are the instructions:

1. Log into your developer account at developer.paypal.com
2. Click on My Account
3. Scroll Down to Direct Credit Cards
4. Click on Enable
5. Click Continue
6. Fill out the information requested

[image: Visual Representation]